# Post meta select input, if statement

Tags: php, metabox, post-meta

I have created a meta box with a select input (drop down menu). It has a few values and I want to display different content depends on which value the user selects. I am just unsure how to display this conditional content with post meta select boxes.

```
<label for="item_one">Item One Select:</label>
<select name="item_one" id="item_one">
    <option value="option1" <?php selected( $item_one_selected, 'option1' ); ?>>Something 1</option>
    <option value="option2" <?php selected( $item_one_selected, 'option2' ); ?>>Something 2</option>
    <option value="option3" <?php selected( $item_one_selected, 'option3' ); ?>>Something 3</option>
</select>
```

Can I do something similar to a checkbox like:

```
<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'metavaluehere', true)) { ?>
//do something 
<? } else { ?>
//do something else
<? } else { ?>
//do something else
<?php } ?>
```

I am just unsure the proper way to form this conditional statement with a metabox select input.

In plain english I'd want this, using the top example:

If option1 is selected do this, else if option 2 is selected do this instead, else if option 3 is selected do this...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Full code here:

```
<?php
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'post_options_box' );
function post_options_box()
{
    add_meta_box( 'post-options-box', 'Post Options', 'post_options_callback', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}


function post_options_callback( $post ){
    $options_values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $item_one_selected = isset( $options_values['item_one'] ) ? esc_attr( $options_values['item_one'][0] ) : '';
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_post_options_meta_nonce', 'post_options_meta_nonce' );
 ?>
 <p>
 <label for="item_one">Item One Select:</label>
    <select name="item_one" id="item_one">
        <option value="option1" <?php selected( $item_one_selected, 'option1' ); ?>>Something 1</option>
        <option value="option2" <?php selected( $item_one_selected, 'option2' ); ?>>Something 2</option>
        <option value="option3" <?php selected( $item_one_selected, 'option3' ); ?>>Something 3</option>
    </select>
   </p>


   <?php    
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'post_options_save' );
function post_options_save ( $post_id )
{
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    if( !isset( $_POST['price_meta_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['price_meta_nonce'], 'my_price_meta_nonce' ) ) return;

    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;



    if( isset( $_POST['item_one'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'item_one', esc_attr( $_POST['item_one'] ) );


}
?>
```

Comment: How is the data saved to the database?

Comment: It's being saved just didnt include that part of the code, didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: But the way it is saved determines what `get_post_meta` gives back and that determines how your conditional will have to work.

Comment: Ok, I am going to add it to the original post, sorry about that.

Comment: ^^ In other words, are you saving a serialized array or several individual key/value pairs?

Comment: key/value pairs....i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this but it looks like something like what you have should work:

```
if ('option1' == get_post_meta($post->ID, 'item_one', true)) { 
  //do something 
} elseif ('option2' == get_post_meta($post->ID, 'item_one', true)) {
  //do something else
} else { 
  //do something else
}
```

You didn't need all those opening and closing tags, and some of them would have caused odd results.

Comment: thanks! this worked but I am using those opening and closing tags you mentioned. The reason is that I need to show/hide div elements according to the meta values; I am unaware of any other way to to do this other than using the tags I posted above; please let me know if there is a better way!! Thanks again!<3

Comment: If you are using the opening and closing tags to switch between PHP and HTMP, then that is what they are for, but in the code the posted you were not doing that.

Comment: Ahh ok, I probably wasn't specific enough in my OP. I thank you so much for helping me out. You made my day.